# How to implement visibility in nativescript with angular

Tags: angular, components, nativescript, visibility

I've got a dead simple nativescript angular component that I'm trying to set the visibility on and extending ContentView doesn't seem to work.

```
 <capture-component [visibility]="'collapse'" top="0" left="0"></capture-component>

 @Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './capture.component.html',
  selector: 'capture-component'
 })
 export class CaptureComponent extends ContentView {

 }
```

Anyone have a clue how to do this correctly? I've tried variations of collapse, 'collapse', collapsed, bound or not bound, etc. Kind frustrating how easy this is to do. I could make a property and set the css but i'd rather use the framework if possible.

Comment: Did you try `[style.visibility]="'collapse'"`?

Comment: It seems as though you can just use `visibility="collapse"` or `visibility="collapsed"`, since at the moment you're not binding the `visibility` property to a property in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a `Input()` visibility in your CaptureComponent and then you an use that in your capture.component.html e.g.

```
 <capture-component [visibility]="'collapse'" top="0" left="0"></capture-component>
```

Let's assume your capture.component.html starts with a GridLayout, then in your html

```
<GridLayout width="100%" height="100%" rows="auto,*" [visibility]="visibility">
```

and in your .ts file

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './capture.component.html',
  selector: 'capture-component'
 })
 export class CaptureComponent extends ContentView {
 @Input() visibility: string;
 }
```

Comment: I know that would work, but figured extending ContentView would already do that for me. Perhaps I'm just assuming too much.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using *ngIf although I feel visibility should work when extending any Base view.